# How do I store my substring between strtok tokens in C?

Tags: c

Basically, I'm using `strtok()` to get rid of extra subsequent whitespace, then using `strcat()` to concatenate the string back so there's only one white space in the string as required. 
For example:
"hello   there." string has 3 whitespaces. My program will successfully `strtok()` the string and then put it back together, so to speak, with just one whitespace. However, when the string looks like this:
"hello   there how are   you?" my program will output: "hello you", discarding everything in between the tokens.

Here's the snippet of my code:

```
void stringFunction(struct dh *header){
    int i;
    char *spaceTk, *spaceString, *holder;
    struct dh *temp;

    temp = header->next;
    while(temp != NULL){
        spaceString = malloc(strlen(temp->string) + 1);
        strcpy(spaceString, temp->string);

        for(i = 0; i < strlen(spaceString) + 1; i++){
            if(spaceString[i] == ' '){
                count++; //don't worry about this variable
                if(spaceString[i] == ' ' && spaceString[i + 1] == ' '){
                    spaceTk = strtok(spaceString, " ");
                    while(spaceTk != NULL){
                        holder = malloc(strlen(spaceTk) + 1);
                        strcpy(holder, spaceTk);
                        spaceTk = strtok(NULL, " ");
                    }
                    strcat(spaceString, " ");
                    strcat(spaceString, holder); 
                    strcpy(temp->string, spaceString);
                }
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

.......

I understand that the variable "holder" stores the tokens, but is overwritten by the very last one. I'm just unsure how to save the words in between the first and last tokens.

Thank you.

Comment: the simplest way would be to just build a new string by concatenating each successive token, using something like `strcat()` with the destination being the new string

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try:

```
char *holders[MAX_STRINGS];
int k= 0;
while(spaceTk != NULL && k<MAX_STRINGS){
    holders[k] = malloc(strlen(spaceTk)+1);
    strcpy(holders[k], spaceTk);
    spaceTk = strtok(NULL, " ");
    k++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your use of `strtok()` is very strange.  One would ordinarily let *it* iterate through the source string to find delimiters, but you appear to be doing that manually, and only then calling `strtok()`.

Additionally, if you have `strdup()` then it is much more convenient than `strlen()` + `malloc()` + `strcpy()`, with identical result (including the same obligation to free the allocated storage when you no longer need it).  If you do not have `strdup()`, and you need to make dynamically-allocated copies of strings, then you should consider *writing* it.

Furthermore, using `strcat()` to copy between objects that overlap -- as you are doing -- produces undefined behavior.  Avoid that at all costs.  Since you're already creating a working copy of the original string, one way to avoid copying between overlapping objects would be to concatenate the pieces into the original string, instead of concatenating them into the working space, and then copying that back to the original string.

Any way around, however, you need to somehow handle each token as you receive it.  Your current code ignores all the tokens between the first and last (leaking memory all the while, too).  Here's a variation on your code that would work better:

```
struct dh *temp;

temp = header->next;
while(temp != NULL){
    char *spaceString = strdup(temp->string);
    // ... need a NULL check on spaceString here, in case allocation failed
    char *first_token = strtok(spaceString, " ");
    char *next_token = strtok(NULL, " ");

    if (next_token) {  // else the original string is OK as-is
        strcpy(temp->string, first_token);
        do {
            strcat(temp->string, " ");
            strcat(temp->string, next_token);
            next_token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        } while (next_token);
    }

    // It is obligatory to free the working string now that we're done with it
    free(spaceString);
}
```

But that's still pretty inefficient (albeit better than yours), because the `strcat()` calls all have to find the end of the string by scanning it from the beginning, not to mention because of the dynamic memory allocation (which is also a potential point of failure) and the function call overhead.  It's not too hard to write code for *in-place* whitespace compression that doesn't suffer from any of those problems.  That might look something like this:

```
char *start_at = strstr(header->next, "  ");

if (start_at) {  // else nothing to do
    char *lag = start_at + 1;  // after the first space
    char *lead = lag + 1;      // after the second space
    int space_count = 2;

    do {
        if (*lead != ' ') {
            // not part of a run of spaces
            space_count = 0;
        } else if (space_count++) {
            // the second or subsequent space in a run of spaces
            continue;
        }

        *lag++ = *lead;
    } while (*lead++);
}
```

Comment: Be careful giving advice around `strdup`, as it is a non-standard function.

Comment: @Oka, you're right, inasmuch as it is not standardized by C.  On the other hand, it *is* standardized by POSIX, so it is perfectly standard in that sense.  I will tweak my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to get rid of multiple spaces (and have a mutable string) you can do that in-place because the output is always smaller than or equal to the input. Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *strip_inter_space(char *s)
{
  int i, j;
  int len;

  len = (int) strlen(s);

  for (i = 0, j = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (s[i] == ' ') {
      // keep one space
      s[j] = s[i];
      j++;
      i++;
      // skip all others
      while (s[i] == ' ') {
        i++;
      }
    }
    // copy the characters we want from beyond the space
    s[j] = s[i];
    j++;
  }
  // strip trailing space if any
  if (s[j - 2] == ' ') {
    s[j - 2] = '\0';
  }
  // terminate string to get rid of the rest
  else {
    s[j] = '\0';
  }
  return s;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  char *cp;

  if (argc < 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s teststring\n", argv[0]);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  // work on copy here, just in case
  cp = malloc(strlen(argv[1]) + 1);
  if (cp == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Malloc failed to allocate a measly %zu bytes\n",
            strlen(argv[1]) + 1);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  strcpy(cp, argv[1]);

  printf("BEFORE: \"%s\"\n", cp);
  cp = strip_inter_space(cp);
  printf("AFTER:  \"%s\"\n", cp);

  free(cp);

  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

You do not need to use the two integers, you could do with a single second pointer and push them around (not shown here) but you won't save much.